# Strings from grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar

I must have dozed off in class. I have an exam tommorow and this is on the review sheet and i have no idea what this means. If someone could explain it and/or have a link for somewhere I can learn about "it" that would be helpful. thanks

> Consider the language that the following grammar defines:
>
> < S > ::= $ | < W > | $< S >
>
> < W > ::= abb | a < W > bb
>
> Write all strings that are in this language and contain seven or fewer character

Edit: Heres another example:

> < Str >::= X< Str > | Y< Another >
> < Another >::= Z | Z< Another >
>
> Write some string in this language that contains more than three characters.

Comment: Why this question has tag `java`?

Comment: This is a [Context Free Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and would be better on [cs.stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: you could google your question to get better answers

Comment: Change the tag. why it is java?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you slept through the class on [Backus–Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

The first example has two rules.

The first:

```
< S > ::= $ | < W > | $< S >
```

Says that `<S>` is either a dollar symbol, a `<W>` or a dollar followed by a `<S>`

The second:

```
< W > ::= abb | a < W > bb
```

Says that `<W>` can be `abb` or can be `a` followed by a `<W>` followed by `bb`

Notice that in this example, an `<S>` can contain another `<S>` and a `<W>` can contain another `<W>`

So the list of all the strings that are less than 8 characters would start:

```
$
$$
$$$
$$$$
$$$$$
$$$$$$
$$$$$$$
```

And that's before we have even considered using the rule for `<W>`.

Lets hope the questions in your exam are more like the second example.
The answer for which could be as simple as `XYZZ`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I didn't even know the name for the concept haha!